# Animation clip taking unexpectedly long time to finish

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I am trying to solve this problem which is really surprise for me. *I have imported some max animation (different train object Animations)*. **I am firing Below method on GUI click which attached to all train object.** This code simultaneously run/fire on different trains Object. Some trains work correctly and animation complete timely while some take long time for animation completion.

```
 public void HourSwitcher(string playShunt)
    {
       gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>().Play(playShunt);
       gameObject.GetComponent<Animation>()[playShunt].speed = 20f;
    }
```

I have also attach my debug logs. As u can see in log 1 image
     **train12 to 16** animation running running while the time 0(surprisingly).
[image]

and in image two train 17 worked correcly but train20-21 running and running
[image]

Comment: What are the warnings about?

Comment: don't worry about warning i have generate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Refer to my this [question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349421/does-culling-affect-animation). It were much disappointing that no one able to identify the problem (maybe lack of much attention to this question). After working 4/5 days finally I got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349421/does-culling-affect-animation).*

**It were mainly animation Culling type Problem**. *For future use and help for the beginners like myself I am going to answer my own question.

### Answer:

My animation culling type were selected to **[BasedOnRenderers](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.BasedOnRenderers.html)** which means that '**Animation is disabled when renderers are not visible**'. i.e., my code were showing me that animation is playing but nothing acutal happening in my scene as my animation were far from camera view.

I **solved** this problem by selecting animation **culling type** to [**AlwaysAnimate**](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.AlwaysAnimate.html) (refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349421/does-culling-affect-animation)). It means that '**object is animated even when offscreen**'.

*My some animation were working correctly because they were coming under the view of camera while some animations were not working (while code showing that it is in play mode) and playing continuously/taking long time because they were far from my camera view.*

*Hope it will help others*

Refer to this Questions also which I were asked (tightly associated with this problem):

1. [Animation unexpected behaviour - Why animation becomes complete If my camera walk through the scene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36301205/animation-unexpected-behaviour-why-animation-becomes-complete-if-my-camera-wal/36350079#36350079)
2. [Does culling affect animation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349421/does-culling-affect-animation)