# Does culling affect animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

I just simply want to know that does culling affect the animation cause i have some culled animation object which some time work and some time not as I move my camera in the scene?

I search on google I found [AnimatorCullingMode](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimatorCullingMode.AlwaysAnimate.html).then I check my animated object in culling type **basedOnredere** is selected. Do I need to change it to **alwaysAnimate**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After working a 4/5 days on this issue, Finally I got the answer(silly me).

Yes culling affect the animation using **animation componen**t's property which is called **[Culling Type](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.html)** as Figure show.

[image]

Previously My all animation **Culling type** were selected to **[BasedOnRenderers](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.BasedOnRenderers.html)** that's why my some animation working while some were playing continuously. As I got that:

**[BasedOnRenderers](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.BasedOnRenderers.html)**: Animation is disabled when renderers are not visible.

This culling method is more suitable when you have renderers attached after import - it will take renderers (like mesh renderers, particle renderers and so on) attached to this gameObject or children of this game object.

***while the option I now selected which have solve the Problem (Al-Hamdullilah)
said***:

**[Always Animate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AnimationCullingType.AlwaysAnimate.html)**: Animation culling is disabled - object is animated even when offscreen.